# 2 way data binding in attribute directive - Angular

Tags: angular

How to use 2 way data binding for an attribute level directive in Angular? I can't use ngModel because I am using this inside a div with contentEditable=true. I want to send the input entered to this div to my  syntax-highlight directive and if there is any change in the text inside  syntax-highlight directive , it should be reflected on UI. How can I do that?

```
 <div id="myTextEditor" maxlength="700" contenteditable="true" syntax-highlight="handleKeyPress">
 </div>
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far. Two way binding has the syntax of `[(attr)]="varaible`

Comment: [(attr)] This doesn't work for contentEditable=true.

Comment: Oh I understand now. You can't do data binding on DOM content like that. You can use @HostLIstener and listen for input events which are fired when the content is edited by the user.

Comment: yes but that is still one way binding. How do I send the entered input back to component where this div is residing?